# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2021

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: elementary OS Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **July 19** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on July 19, users can [nominate themselves](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/election/2). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On July 26, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than two candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on August 3 (or on the 10th, if we need to extend the nomination period).

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The nominations for the election have been extended for another week (until August 2, 2021) as we need more candidates. Please consider helping the moderation team and keep this site alive, by nominating in [the election page](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/election/2)!